# Union ALL with different number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an Employee table with these columns :

- EmployeeId
- Fullname
- Phone
- Department
- Team
- Function
- Manager

and EmployeeHistory containing the history with different columns, but there are some in common :

- EmployeeId
- Fullname
- Email
- Geolocation
- Department
- Team
- Function
- Manager

How can I union them?

Comment: Replace uncommon columns by dummy values.

Answer (score 3):

Replace uncommon columns by dummy values.

```
SELECT 
EmployeeId ,
Fullname   ,
'Undefined' AS Email,
Phone      ,
'Undefined' AS Geolocation
Department ,
Team       ,
[Function]   ,
Manager    
FROM Employee

UNION ALL

EmployeeId ,
Fullname   ,
Email      ,
'0000000000' AS Phone,
Geolocation,
Department ,
Team       ,
[Function]   ,
Manager    
FROM EmployeeHistory
```

Comment: only thing id suggest to add is an explanation of why it needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `null` (or suitable value) to replace non-existent columns

```
select EmployeeId, Fullname, Email, Geolocation, null Phone, Department, Team, function, Manager
from EmployeeHistory
union all
select EmployeeId, Fullname, null,  null, Phone, Department, Team, function, Manager
from Employee
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `union` or `union all` number of columns must match in all the select lists. To do so you can use null as value in missing columns within any select list.

Though you already got your answer with `union all`, you need to use union instead of there is any possibilities of having duplicate rows and you want to select only distinct one.

```
Select EmployeeId, Fullname, null as Email, Phone, null as Geolocation, Department, Team, Function, Manager from Employee
union
Select EmployeeId, Fullname, Email, null as Phone, Geolocation, Department, Team, Function, Manager from EmployeeHistory
```